# Flask AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: home

Tags: flask

I'm trying to code a social network with flask on python anywhere
, everything was working fine before and without touching the imports I started to receive this error when I run routes.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/OurHub/mysite/routes.py", line 13, in <module>
    def home():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/scaffold.py", line 433, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/scaffold.py", line 54, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1084, in add_url_rule
    raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: home
```

I tried to put everything in a single file and I don't have two functions that have the same name
here is the start of my routes.py code

```
import os
import secrets
from PIL import Image
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request, abort
from __init__ import app, db, bcrypt
from forms import FormCreerCompte, FormConnecter, ModifierCompte, FormPoste
from modelsdb import Profil, Poste
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    page = request.args.get('page',1, type=int)
    posts = Poste.query.paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    return render_template('page1.html', posts=posts)
```

and the code from the innit file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '6dfde280ba245'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://OurHub:ninjQ@OurHub.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com/OurHub$default'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view= 'connecter'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'primary'

import routes
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I tried to delete a piece of code that I had commented in my html file and it worked! Maybe because the html comment `"<!-->"` doesn't work with python code inserts `"{%%}"`. The error still appears when I run route, but the application works fine, I was looking for the error in the wrong place after all.